# Type '' is not assignable to type 'JwtConfig'

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, google-oauth

I need to put those line into my code.
but this error keeps appearing and I'm stuck with this, being not able to find the solution.
Please help me.

> Type '{ tokenGetter: () => string; whitelistedDomains: string[]; blacklistedRoutes: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type 'JwtConfig'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'whitelistedDomains' does not exist in type 'JwtConfig'.ts(2322)
> angular-jwt.module.d.ts(14, 5): The expected type comes from property 'config' which is declared here on type 'JwtModuleOptions'

underlined error occurs at `whitelistedDomains`

app.module.ts

```
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    .
    .
    AppRoutingModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config:{
        tokenGetter:() => {
          return localStorage.getItem('access_token');

        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:8080'],
        blacklistedRoutes:[]
      }
    })
       
    ],
```

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the [`JwtConfig`](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/main/projects/angular-jwt/src/lib/angular-jwt.module.ts#L13) interface, the `whitelistedDomains` and `blacklistedRoutes` properties are not to be found. Probably you were looking for `allowedDomains` and `disallowedRoutes` properties. Try the following

```js
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config:{
    tokenGetter:() => {
      return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    },
    allowedDomains: ['localhost:8080'],
    disallowedRoutes:[]
  }
})
```

Comment: If you look at that same file on earlier versions, the variables were apparently renamed from whitelistDomains to allowedDomains. Refer 4.2.0: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/v4.2.0/projects/angular-jwt/src/lib/angular-jwt.module.ts

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael D.
When I woke up and tried to apply it, almost all part of app.modules.ts was underlined and I installed jet again, and it was all fixed. but I guess this problem will occur again. So I will use this next time it happens !! Thank you, again!!